# Can you send a packet without being visible to the receiver?

Tags: networking, network-programming, udp, ip, packet

Can you send data to a UDP receiver without your IP address or location visible to the receiver?

Comment: You don't need to have your IP address included unless you want them to be able to respond. You can spoof any info in a packet; you just need to accept the consequences of the changes you make.

Comment: note that because intermediate devices (e.g. switches) see the packet a sufficiently advanced adversary might be able to figure out what was going on.  this becomes easier as more packets are sent along the same, or similar, routes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. It's possible to create and send UDP packets with a spoofed IP address using a [raw socket](https://linux.die.net/man/7/raw).

Raw sockets allow applications to create their own IP headers including the source address fields. Look around for examples in whatever language you write in.

However, creating and sending such a packet doesn't mean that the networks along the way to the recipient will actually deliver it. Some networks employ defensed like [Reverse path forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse-path_forwarding) to protect against [IP spoofing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address_spoofing). There's CAIDA a [research project](https://www.caida.org/projects/spoofer/) that tests for IP spoofing in networks around the world, you can find an up to date report [here](https://spoofer.caida.org/summary.php).